# Mapping SQL View to JPA Entity

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, jpa

In my development project, I am using JPA (hibernate) as OR Mapping technology for database access. I sometimes hit performance issues and technical difficulties when I map DB table to entities directly for complex relationship.

I find a workaround is to map DB view to JPA entities. This make coding easier and sometimes performance is better. Do you think it is a anti-pattern of using JPA in this way?

Comment: Whatever works better for you is obviously not an "anti-pattern". You know best what works better for you ...

Answer (score 12):

**This is not a workaround and not an anti-pattern.** There is a topic on [mapping JPA Entities to SQL Views](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/mapping_jpa_entities_to_sql_views_it_works_even_w.html).
It gives you enough information whether to use this method or not.

Personally, I prefer Java classes, and thus I use [Result Classes Constructor Expression](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_). It instantiates and populates objects of provided class based on results query return.

You can view both of these methods which increases performance and reduces structure complexity.

Comment: I also prefer mapping the result with a result class, but I have some doubts about the custom entity approach. According to the spec, JPA entities must have an `@Id` field; however, you can have a view with duplicate records. How do you handle that situation?

Comment: Thats a good question. Do you think creating a hash column from multiple columns of the view would help? It could act as the primary key.

Comment: @JMelnik I too would love to achieve with Java classes. I have a question regarding Constructor Expressions and my question is if Constructor Expressions are used, how ORDER BY attribute is used? See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852430/jpql-not-a-selected-expression-error) where I have a complex query and I unable to do ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the link JMelnik kindly provided:
  I created the complex query as a View in Javadb, then tried to drag the view onto the form, but Netbeans was not allowing me to drop it (therefore I could not autocreate the bound table.  I saw on that link I'm not the only one who experienced this.

Solution that worked for me:

Create View in db, for your complex SQL with Joins

"Create entity from database" in entities package, and name it xxxViewName

- Ensure a field in the entity is identified as key, by adding "@Id" above it.

Create java persistence query in the Navigator :

- Ensure form design is visible, then right click "Other components" in Navigator, and choose Add From Palette > Java Persistence > Query
- Configure the query: Do NOT use the usual "show xxxViewName" (which fails because JPA does not support show).  Use Select  w from xxxViewName w"

Create java persistence result List in the Navigator :

- Similar to creating the Query.  Be sure to set List's Type Parameters to

Bind your JTable to the list.