# JPQL Not a Selected Expression error

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have the following JPQL in ProductList Entity class which executes as expected.

```
select DISTINCT new foo.bar.ProductListDTO(p.prodId, " +
CASE WHEN (p.prodId = 'ZCX') THEN CONCAT(p.prodDesc, ' - ', e.userId)
ELSE p.prodDesc END)  from   
ProductList p  LEFT JOIN p.productCatalogueList c  where c.userId='ZAM'
```

ProductListDTO class

```
public ProductListDTO(String prodId, String prodDesc, String userId) {

    this.prodId = prodId;
    this.prodName = prodDesc;
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is add `ORDER BY`  to the query. When `p.prodDesc` is added to `ORDER BY` clause, I am getting error
`not a SELECTed expression` because p.prodDesc is not a selected field. if I add `prodName` from `ProductListDTO` class then it would 
give error `The identification variable 'appDesc' is not defined in the FROM clause`.

How can I do `ORDER BY` prodDesc as I am using ProductListDTO constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, looks like your constructor is expecting 3 columns, but you are calling if with only 2 columns.

Second, seems like your problem is because of the CASE inside the SELECT to construct the ProductListDTO.

I would suggest to move your logic from query to the constructor, to make something like this:

```
    select DISTINCT new foo.bar.ProductListDTO(p.prodId, p.prodDesc, e.userId) from   
    ProductList p  LEFT JOIN p.productCatalogueList c  where c.userId='ZAM'
    ORDER BY p.prodDesc

public ProductListDTO(String prodId, String prodDesc, String userId) {    
    this.prodId = prodId;
    if ("ZCX".equals(prodId)) {
       this.prodDesc = prodDesc + " - " + userId;
    } else {
       this.prodDesc = prodDesc;
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is a good alternate idea of moving case statement to constructor. Thanks